# Making a chat client window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'll start with code

```
import socket;
from Tkinter import *;

#Initalize tkinter
root = Tk();
App = root;
root.title("Client");
root.configure(bg = "#DEE2E3");
App.geometry("400x450");

#Input
typeBox = Entry(root, text = '');
send = Button(root, text = 'Send', bg = "#A0DEF2", font = ('times', 14, 'bold'));
typeBox.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X);
send.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X);

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
host = 'localhost';
port = 5500;

#connect to server
s.connect((host, port));

#chat
while(True):
    message = raw_input("Message: ");
    s.send(message);
    data = s.recv(1024);
    print(data);

root.mainloop();
```

I want to get the information from the entry widget. Then when click send I want it to show on the client and sends to server.(I've changed message to equal typeBox,but then it spams data sent in server.)

Comment: Yes I just have a habit of putting them

Comment: To be fair, semi-colons are completely valid, and very commonplace in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop runs forever, that is why it spams when you don't have the raw_input to pause the spam. You need to put that code into a function (without the while loop), that function can then be assigned as the command for the button.

```
def cmd_send():
    message = typeBox.get()
    s.send(message)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
```

This function needs to be defined sometime before you create the send Button. To add this as a command to the button, include the option:

command = cmd_send

So for your button it would turn out to be:

```
send = Button(root, text = 'Send', bg = "#A0DEF2", font = ('times', 14, 'bold'), command = cmd_send)
```

And get rid of all the ; at the end of your lines ;-)

**EDIT:**

Add a Text widget to display your message. Since I don't have the server code, I have only tested inserting directly. You can add a Text widget like:

```
output = Text(root, font=('times', 14))
output.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
```

This could be inserted at the same place you make and pack the Entry and Button widgets. Then replace print(data) in the cmd_send function with:

```
output.insert(END, data + "\n")
```

This will insert the data you receive at the end of the Text Widget, and add a newline. New Mexico Tech has a [good reference for Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html). And [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/) also have some nice info.

Comment: Thank you it sends to server, but I want it to show on the client itself since its going to be a chat between two people.

Comment: You'll need to add a widget that presents the data. Perhaps a [Text widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html).

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot.